# Quelle est la différence entre "prédire" et "anticiper"?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Comme le titre indique, quelle est la différence entre "**prédire**" et "**anticiper**"?

Je pense qu'on peut les utiliser de façon interchangeable.

Ai-je raison?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prédire insinue qu'on sait ce qu'il va se passer. Anticiper insinue qu'on essaye de savoir ce qui peut arriver, et qu'on agit en conséquence.

Il y a donc 2 différences majeures :

1.

- Prédire ne fait que relater un fait.
- Anticiper implique une action faite pour éviter un problème futur.

2.

- Prédire implique qu'on utilise un discours dans lequel il n'y a pas d'alternative selon la personne qui parle (une voyante prédit l'avenir, un scientifique prédit la fin du monde...). Cela n'empêche pas que la personne peut se tromper.
- Anticiper implique qu'on imagine ce qui peut se passer (on anticipe généralement plusieurs événements).

Sources : [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pr%C3%A9dire)

Answer (score 6):

**[prédire](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pr%C3%A9dire/63424?q=pr%C3%A9dire#62713)**

> Annoncer d'avance ce qui doit arriver, par intuition, raisonnement ou conjecture, par une inspiration prétendument surnaturelle :
>
> > *Prédire l'avenir. Prédire une révolution.*
>
> Laisser présager quelque chose, le rendre probable :
>
> > *Les échecs du plan prédisent un avenir très sombre.*

**[anticiper](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/anticiper/3987?q=anticiper#3979)**

> Agir comme si on pouvait disposer de quelque chose qui n'existe pas encore :
>
> > *Il a anticipé sur l'héritage de son oncle.*
>
> Révéler ce qui, dans un discours, un récit, ne doit être connu que plus tard :
>
> > *Mais j'anticipe, et ne voudrais pas gâcher mon récit.*
>
> Prévoir, supposer ce qui va arriver et adapter sa conduite à cette supposition :
>
> > *Politicien qui anticipe sur les élections à venir.*

On peut voir que *prédire* a ce radical de *dire* ainsi, il va plus s'agir d'**annoncer un chose future**.

Alors qu'*anticiper* sera **une/des action(s) planifiée(s) à l'avance**. ( *ant*[é]=avant + *capere*=prendre == [prendre les devants](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_les_devants) )